# Flutter - use WillPopScope with custom dialog to confirm app exit

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I've implemented app exit confirmation this way:

```
 return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _promptExit,
      child: Container() /*Remaining window layout*/
```

`_promptExit` funcion shows dialog to confirm exit:

```
return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
        title: new Text(Strings.prompt_exit_title),
        content: new Text(Strings.prompt_exit_content),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: new Text(Strings.no),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          FlatButton(
            child: new Text(Strings.yes),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ??
        false;
```

It works, but I want to use custom dialog instead of standard one: https://github.com/marcos930807/awesomeDialogs

It calls `showDialog` internally, so I tried this way:

```
 AwesomeDialog dlg = AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
      animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
      title: Strings.prompt_exit_title,
      desc: Strings.prompt_exit_content,
      dismissOnBackKeyPress: false,
      useRootNavigator: true,
      btnCancelOnPress: () {  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);},
      btnOkOnPress: () {   Navigator.of(context).pop(true);},
      btnOkText: Strings.yes,
      btnCancelText: Strings.no
    );

    return dlg.show() ?? false;
```

But I can't pop this way, I am getting black screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. So that's how it should look:

```
Future<bool> _promptExit()  async {

    bool canExit;

    AwesomeDialog dlg = AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
      animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
      title: Strings.prompt_exit_title,
      desc: Strings.prompt_exit_content,
      dismissOnTouchOutside: true,
      btnCancelOnPress: () => canExit = false,
      btnOkOnPress: () => canExit = true,
      btnOkText: Strings.yes,
      btnCancelText: Strings.no
    );

    await dlg.show();
    return Future.value(canExit);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`showDialog` will not pop the dialog itself. So you need to use  `Navigator.of(context).pop()` and get the return value.

`awesomeDialogs` wrap the pop() function itself and do nothing to the return value ([awesome_dialog.dart](https://github.com/marcos930807/awesomeDialogs/blob/master/lib/awesome_dialog.dart))

```
   ...
    pressEvent: () {
      dissmiss();
      btnOkOnPress?.call();
    },
   ...
    pressEvent: () {
      dissmiss();
      btnCancelOnPress?.call();
    },
   ...

dissmiss() {
  if (!isDissmisedBySystem) Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator:useRootNavigator)?.pop();
}
...
```

So you need to handle the return value by yourself and don't use pop() again:

```
var result;

AwesomeDialog dlg = AwesomeDialog(
  context: context,
  dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
  animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
  title: Strings.prompt_exit_title,
  desc: Strings.prompt_exit_content,
  dismissOnBackKeyPress: false,
  useRootNavigator: true,
  btnCancelOnPress: () {result = false;},
  btnOkOnPress: () {result = true;},
  btnOkText: Strings.yes,
  btnCancelText: Strings.no
);

await dlg.show();

return result;
```